# Add a key value pair to results from Laravel Model with pagination

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

In my controller i am calling my invoices model which is doing a paginated selected. After i get the results i then need to loop through each result and add a key => value pair to the original results. 
I have my laravel set up in config/database.php to get results as arrays:

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,

My code in my controller is

```
    $invoices = Invoices::getInvoices($clientId);
    $total = 0;
    foreach($invoices as $key=>$inv) {

        $payments = Payments::getPaymentAmount($inv['InvoiceId']);

        foreach($payments as $pmt) {

                $total += $pmt['Pmt_Amount'];

        }

        $invoices[$key]['total'] = $total;
    }
```

My Invoices Model is:

```
public static function getInvoices($clientId)
{
   $invoices = DB::table('invoices')
    ->where('ClientId', '=', $clientId)
    ->paginate(25);
   return $invoices;
}
```

and my payments model

```
public static function getPaymentAmount($invoiceId)
{
    $payment = DB::table('payments')
        ->select('Pmt_Amount', 'PaymentStatusId')
        ->where('InvoiceId', $invoiceId)
        ->get();

    return $payment;
}
```

When i try to add 'total' to the invoices array i get the following error

Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator has no effect

Comment: Why are you using `DB` in an Eloquent model to call the table that model should be responsible for?

Answer (score 0):

Your $invoices is object, try toArray() after your getInvoices() function :

```
$invoices = $invoices->toArray();
```

Comment: That worked but now my data is full array - after i added the value i needed is there a way to convert it back to the Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator Object format so that my blade template can work as before?